# StarCraft2: ladder reset - does it reset amount of games played?

Tags: starcraft-2

Here is explained what is ladder reset: [What is a ladder reset?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-a-ladder-reset)

Am I correctly understand that during that:

1. ladder/league position/score will be reset;
2. amount of games played will be kept;
3. hidden rank will be kept;
4. you will need to play 5 qualification matches again, after that you will be/could be re-qualified into new league with scores beginning from 0.

Is there something else?

Comment: This is mostly a duplicate of the question you linked. If you have further questions, you could post them as comments to the answer there. Bear in mind that not everything is known about resets and it's all subject to change, as Blizzard has not implemented one yet.

Comment: I believe Blizzard said there would only be one qualification match, which in reality presumably serves no purpose other than to establish that you still play. Leagues would be determined based on MMR, likely meaning you'd stay put. All that said, I agree this is an unanswerable question.

Comment: Lee, Good answer. Why don't you make it as real answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Point 1 through 3 are correct. No information is known about 4, it is unknown how or when a ladder reset will be executed.

A Blizzard employee has stated that as soon as the Grand Masters League is activated (just introduced with patch 1.2.0) a placement match will be needed for everyone, but this is just to trigger a placement event and you will almost surely end up in the league you are currently in.

If this really is the case it is also likely that the points and bonus pools will be reset.

Comment: Are you sure the Grand Master league exists yet? Blizzard claimed there would be two new leagues; Master and Grand Master, though only the former seems to have materialised.

Answer (score 4):

> **Q: I have heard that Season 2 will begin soon. Is it true?**
>   In the next future Season 1 will end and Season 2 will start. We'll see a reset of the various leagues, of course nobody will lose any achievement and there will be a new menu where we'll be able to keep track of old seasons. After that you will need to do only 1 qualifying match, because matchmaking system will not have any reset and will continue to have a complete history of our match in order to offer always better opponents, with an appropriate skill level.
>
> **Q: Will be there new Leagues?**
>   Yes, with patch 1.2 we have seen the Master League and soon there will be the Grand Master. Grand Master will be the top 200 of our region and will be visible to all players.
>
> — http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/859358086#2

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact that a ladder reset hasn't happened yet, it is impossible to predict how it will be done.